# Working with text-files in PHP

Tags: php, text-files

As mentioned before, I am a beginner when it comes to PHP coding. I have made a text file which has my students information, as per below - this includes their name, marks for subjects, e-mail address and date of registration:

Ann Thompson : 50,90,82,64,75 : ann@amuniversity.com: 2016-02-01

Jeremiah Hanson: 80, 75, 88 : jeremiah@amuniversity.com: 2016-03-02

Billy Jones: 89, 72, 46, 54 : billy@amuniversity.com: 2016-04-12

and I have also made a form which inputs a field which takes in the filename which the user wishes to read from and a field for the filename which the user wishes to write to.

Where do I start to get the output below?

Summary for students:

- Ann Thompson enrolled in 2016-02-01, has an average of 48, with a symbol F.
- Jeremiah Hanson enrolled in ....
- Billy Jones enrolled in ....

It should also show the date at the bottom when it was last modified.

Please kindly help

Comment: working with text files are a LOT of work; why aren't you using a database for this, or is this an exercise?

Comment: Should *really* be in a database - do you really intend to leave unencrypted text files, containing students grades and email addresses on a university server? I give it maybe 15 minutes before they're all straight **A** students if you do.

Comment: @Fred-ii- As I said, I am new with PHP coding. I am first trying to work out how to do it with a text-file for testing purposes

Comment: well, take it from experience @Zera text files are lot of work and stands to hold many potential problems and they are numerous. One of which being; once a text file has been modified in any way, there's no going back unless you made provisions to make a copy of it/them. Best way; use a database, which will make retrieval a lot easier and faster in certain respects. You can also work with them though in conjunction with a database and export it, that is an option also.

Comment: @Zera If you insist, then all you'd have to do is do `fread()` and split those data into their individual bits. It may not be the most convenient, but it will get what you want.

Comment: @RepeaterCreeper if I do fread() how about linking the text file to work out the average and to get the summary mentioned above?

Comment: Like I said, split it using `explode()`. The fact that you have a ':' at the end of each data, you could definitely use it. It would become `explode(':')` and that would split your data into: Name, Grade, Email, and Date. And then do it again for grades using the delimiter ',' this time and then you can calculate whatever you have to. (Not the most convenient, but it works.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the following code. I commented on the code wherever I thought needed. Let me know if you don't understand something from it. And obviously, you need to update the checkGrade function as per your grade system, but you get the idea :)

```
<?php
// Read the input file line by line into "input" array
$filename = "input.txt";
$input = explode("\n", file_get_contents($filename));

// Go through each line
for($i = 0; $i < sizeOf($input); $i++){

    // split line by :
    $line = explode(":", $input[$i]);

    // Initialize variables based on position
    $name = $line[0];
    $numbers = $line[1];
    $email = $line[2];
    $registration = $line[3];

    // Calculate average
    // Remove any spaces first from the numbers
    $numbers = str_replace(' ', '', $numbers);
    // Split the numbers by ,
    $numbersArray = explode(",", $numbers);
    $sum = 0;
    // Calculate sum
    for($j = 0; $j < sizeOf($numbersArray); $j++){
        $num = (int)$numbersArray[$j];
        $sum += $num;
    }
    $avg = $sum/sizeof($numbersArray);

    // Print it
    echo "$name enrolled in $registration, has an average of $avg, with a symbol ". checkGrade($avg) ."<br>";

}

// Last modified date of the input file
echo "<br><br><br>";
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "This file was last modified: " . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($filename));
}

function checkGrade($num){
    if ($num < 65){
        $grad = 'F';
    }
    else if ($num<= 66 && $num >=65){
        $grad = 'D';
    }
    else if ($num <= 69 && $num >=67){
        $grad = 'D+'; 
    }
    else if ($num <= 73 && $num >=70){
        $grad = 'C-';
    }
    else if ($num <= 76 && $num >=74){
        $grad = 'C';
    }
    else if ($num<= 79 && $num >=77 ){
        $grad = 'C+';
    }
    else if ($num <= 83 && $num >=80){
        $grad = 'B-'; 
    }
    else if ($num <= 86 && $num >=84){
        $grad = 'B';
    }
    else if ($num <= 89 && $num >=87){
        $grad = 'B+';
    }
    else if ($num <= 93 && $num >=90){
        $grad = 'A-';
    }
    else if ($num <= 96 && $num >=94){
        $grad = 'A';
    }
    else if ($num >= 97){
        $grad = 'A+';
    }
    return $grad;
}
?>
```

Here is the output:

```
Ann Thompson enrolled in 2016-02-01, has an average of 72.2, with a symbol C-
Jeremiah Hanson enrolled in 2016-03-02, has an average of 81, with a symbol B-
Billy Jones enrolled in 2016-04-12, has an average of 65.25, with a symbol D



This file was last modified: May 03 2017 13:12:13.
```

Comment: Happy to help, no problemo! ^_^